# Requests unable to find a table Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the strikeout odds data [here](https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php) in the form of a Python dataframe.

Below is my code:

```py
games = "[https://www.fantasypros.com/mlb/schedules/](https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php)"

page = requests.get(games)

games_frame = pd.read_html(page.text, displayed_only=False)\[1\]
```

Comment: You have two links in your question (*fantasypros and rotowire*). Can you specify which one ?

Comment: `pd.read_html` is not going to work here. You're going to need to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the data and read it in as a JSON. If you look at the HTML, you'll see each table's data is actually a JSON: `data: [{"gameID":"2513620","playerID":"13902","firstName":"Mark","lastName":"Mathias", ...`

Comment: it is the rotowire link, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

script_tag = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'script' and tag.text and '"Strikeouts"' in tag.text)

data = re.search(r"data:\s*(\[.*\])", script_tag.text)
data = json.loads(data.group(1))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
    gameID playerID firstName lastName             name team   opp                                                                  logo                                      playerLink draftkings_strikeouts draftkings_strikeoutsUnder draftkings_strikeoutsOver fanduel_strikeouts fanduel_strikeoutsUnder fanduel_strikeoutsOver mgm_strikeouts mgm_strikeoutsUnder mgm_strikeoutsOver pointsbet_strikeouts pointsbet_strikeoutsUnder pointsbet_strikeoutsOver
0  2512637    12854     Jacob   deGrom     Jacob deGrom  TEX    KC  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100TEX.png?v=6     /betting/mlb/player/jacob-degrom-odds-12854                   9.5                       -140                       105                9.5                    -138                    108           None                None               None                 None                      None                     None
1  2511983    12739    Shohei   Ohtani    Shohei Ohtani  LAA   WAS  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100LAA.png?v=6    /betting/mlb/player/shohei-ohtani-odds-12739                   7.5                       -150                       105                7.5                    -122                   -106           None                None               None                 None                      None                     None
2  2512064    10510    Gerrit     Cole      Gerrit Cole  NYY  @CLE  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100NYY.png?v=6      /betting/mlb/player/gerrit-cole-odds-10510                   6.5                        105                      -135                6.5                     108                   -136           None                None               None                 None                      None                     None
3  2513620    14482  Cristian   Javier  Cristian Javier  HOU  @PIT  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100HOU.png?v=6  /betting/mlb/player/cristian-javier-odds-14482                   6.5                       -110                      -120                6.5                    -124                   -102           None                None               None                 None                      None                     None
4  2512307    15116     Pablo    Lopez      Pablo Lopez  MIN   CWS  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100MIN.png?v=6      /betting/mlb/player/pablo-lopez-odds-15116                   6.5                                                                     6.5                    -158                    124           None                None               None                 None                      None                     None
```